# unable to upgrade gdal-bin from 1.9 to 1.10 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gdal, installation, carto

I am trying to install import files to cartodb installed on local machine. But import fails with these errors like

```
Error 2001 unable to load data
Error 3009 SHP normalization error
```

Also the ruby console says the ogr2ogr error. So tried to update **gdal-bin 1.10.x**. Current version of gdal-bin is **1.9.2**. But during the sudo-apt get install gdal-bin, these error appears

```
gdal-bin : Depends: libgdal1h (>= 1.10.0-1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Tried to add gdal 1.10 ppa to system. Also removed older version. But not successful.

Answer (score 1):

About the 1.10 gdal upgrade:

It seems that you have some conflicts (probably a program depends on the lib). Don't worry you can use [aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude) which will create a solution fo your conflict and try to repair it.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude
```

In case you are wondering, `apt-get` is a striped down version of aptitude, excellent for everyday usage but lucks versatility of aptitude.

Comment: Solved. Installed/updated some packages
gdal-bin 1.9
libgdal1-dev 1.9
python-gdal 1.9
ogr2ogr --version 1.10